# Importing Taxonomy from CSV

Tags: taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I know that there are a couple of modules to import taxonomy from CSV but my taxonomy has many term references inside it.

Attached is a screenshot of my taxonomy, how can I import the excel sheet into it? Please help

[image]

excel sheet.
[image]

Comment: It's better to mention your drupal version, is it drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Yes, Drupal 7 it is.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically speaking, for term references you need to use the Term ID rather than the actual term name.

Luckily, the D7 [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module comes with a feature where it fetches the Term ID automatically for you based on the Term Name.

Here is an example of one of my mappings:

[image]